# Preventing recalculation of instances on two unified meshes

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I try to instance objects on two unified meshes with a `mesh boolean` node. The problem is that when the mesh changes, the instances are recalculated on the points:

[image]

I understood from a number of people that a solution may be found by using the new UV nodes in Blender 3.4 Alpha (`UV unwrap` and `Pack UV islands`). I've been messing around for a few days and this is my node tree so far:

[image]

I have tried to use the *Intersecting Edges* of the `Mesh Boolean` node as a *seam* in the `UV unwrap` node etc. but so far without success.

Does anyone have an idea how to prevent recalculation and how to add or remove instances at the location of the seam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, `Distribute Points on Faces` creates a new distribution of points at every minimal change of the underlying mesh.

To avoid this, you would have to apply the node to both surfaces together first, and then apply the `Mesh Boolean` node afterwards.

Then, by comparing the positions of the points with those of the remaining faces, you can create a selection with which you can remove the excess points:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

---

**Update**

If you want to align the instances to the surface, just plug in the *Rotation* from `Distribute Points on Faces`:

[image]

Comment: Tnx for your sollution! This keeps the points on place :) Would you please also add the instancing on points to your node tree, as I have in my example in the question? With this solution I have problems with the orientation of instances along the normal. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EwSa That's what you meant, right? (see update)

Comment: Thnx a lot! This is what I meant :)