# Geometry nodes: smooth transition between two mesh boolean connected objects

Tags: geometry-nodes

In [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271323/controlling-opening-paraboloid-in-plane-with-geometry-nodes) question I described the context that I'm striving for. After several attempts and with Quellenform's help on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273684/preventing-recalculation-of-instances-on-two-unified-meshes) question, I'm getting close to a result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

By means of the `geometry proximity` node I want to create a somewhat organic transition (smooth transition) between the plane and the sphere, so that it looks like a bubble is being blown out of the plane (when reversing the animation). The start of the movement is fine, except for the transition between plane and sphere. At the end, where the sphere enters the plane, the plane deforms into a kind of crater figure, where the transition between the plane and the sphere must be smooth, so that it looks like *one* mesh.

I had hoped that a `subdivision surface` would provide a smooth transition, but that's not the case. I've been playing with a `float curve`, `ColorRamp` and `MapRange`, but I'm not getting the desired effect yet. How can I achieve this effect in geometry nodes? The intention is that I can place instances on the points of this bubble shaped mesh later, so please keep that in mind.

Comment: Just to give you something to think about: You can't force a round shape into a square one without creating artifacts in the movement. The mesh topology does not allow this. But you can connect a round shape with a round one. https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Dh4.jpg

Comment: Tnx a lot! :-) Did you just replace the square for a circle with a subdivide node in my node tree? Maybe I could use a mask to make it a "square".

Comment: Here I have connected the top of a cylinder with a UV sphere for test purposes.